How do I get all data from an API when I don't know the max number of pages
I am pulling data using an API, Python, and the requests package. I want to pull all the data, but have only been able to pull 4,000 rows. How do I pull all of the data? The number of pages is not present in the response. I don't know how many rows are in the data, but it's more than 4,000.
Here is the working code that can pull 4,000 rows, though some of the details need to remain private:
headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <generated_token_put_here>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'verify':'/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
}

data = '{"pageSize": 2000, "pageNumber": 100}' #his is the largest pageSize and pageNumber values that will still return data. 

response = requests.post('<api_endpoint_put_here>', headers=headers, verify=True, data=data)


What does the response look like if you ask for a non-existent pageNumber?

If I enter any pageNumber above 100, it returns an empty response: '[]'. If l leave pageNumber out completely, I get a 400 error that say "JSON deserialization 'Requests.Entities.Requests.RequestRequest" was missing require properties, including the following: pageNumber". If I enter pageNumber:0, I get a 400 error that "Page Number should be greater than 0."

When you don't know the total number of pages, a simple method would be to iterate over the pages and then once you reach a page that has less than the number of expected rows, you know that's the last page or if there is an exact number of rows that fits the last page, then checking the page after the last page will return an empty set of data.
Here's an implementation of that (you may have to adjust this slightly depending on how the API formats their data:
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <generated_token_put_here>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'verify': '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
}

page_size = 2000
page_number = 1
all_data = []

while True:

    data = f'{{"pageSize": {page_size}, "pageNumber": {page_number}}}'
    response = requests.post('<api_endpoint_put_here>', headers=headers, verify=True, data=data)
    
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Error: Received status code {response.status_code}")
        break
    
    response_data = response.json()  # Adjust if the response is not JSON
    if not response_data: # The previous page was the last page and had the same number of rows as pageSize
        break
    
    all_data.extend(response_data)  # or something like response_data['items'] if data is nested under 'items'
    
    if len(response_data) < page_size: # you've reached the last page
        break
    
    page_number += 1

print(f"Total rows pulled: {len(all_data)}")


This worked! Thank you very much!

I was studying the code to make sure I understand it. "if not response_data / break" is supposed to catch if the last page has an exact number of entries as the page_size, right? I'm not sure how it does that. Does it break if the response_data is blank?

Yes, so if the response_data is empty (i.e. not response_data is true), then that means that the current page is 1 greater than the final page of data. This only happens if the final page of data had exactly the same amount of data as the page_size and so our other last page check if len(response_data) < page_size wasn't triggered.
